# Is there a standard way to categorize custom error types

Tags: go

Is there an accepted pattern for grouping custom error types together so that I can handle them differently according to their group?

For example, here's what I would do in C# with exceptions:

```
abstract class FriendlyException : ApplicationException {
    protected FriendlyException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
class MyNiceException : FriendlyException {
    public MyNiceException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

I could then do something different in the `catch` depending on whether or not it falls into that category:

```
try { DoSomething(); }
catch (FriendlyException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
catch { Console.WriteLine("Unhandled error"); }
```

In Go, I see that I can use `As` or switch directly on the type, but since there are implicit interfaces, I'm not seeing that this can be done without a wasted interface member, like this:

```
type FriendlyError interface { SomeWastedMethod() }
type MyFriendlyError struct {}
func (fe MyFriendlyError) SomeWastedMethod() {}
func (fe MyFriendlyError) Error() string { return "implementing error interface" }
```

I could then check to see if an error is of that group like this:

```
var fe FriendlyError
err := DoSomething()
if err != nil {
    if errors.As(err, &fe) {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Unhandled error")
    }
}
```

That wasted method in the `MyFriendlyError` struct is what bothers me. Is that the only way to accomplish this, or is there some other standard pattern?

In my example, I would want multiple different error types, some of which are safe to return the message to the caller, and some of which I want to just give the caller a generic message, while still retaining the details for internal logging.

Comment: You can use error wrapping and wrap all the errors in one struct and use that struct as your group and handle it.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani Do you have an example or a link to that strategy? It sounds good but I think I need to see it in action.

Comment: I've added an answer with this solution, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following way:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    ErrInvalidMsg   = errors.New("invalid message")
    ErrInvalidParam = errors.New("invalid param")
    ErrBadMsg       = errors.New("bad message")
)

type GroupError1 struct {
    Base error
}

func (ge GroupError1) Error() string {
    return ge.Base.Error()
}

type GroupError2 struct {
    Base error
}

func (ge GroupError2) Error() string {
    return ge.Base.Error()
}

func TheError(n int) error {
    switch n % 3 {
    case 0:
        return GroupError2{
            Base: ErrBadMsg,
        }
    case 1:
        return GroupError1{
            Base: ErrInvalidParam,
        }
    case 2:
        return GroupError1{
            Base: ErrInvalidMsg,
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := TheError(1); err != nil {
        var ge1 GroupError1
        var ge2 GroupError2

        if ok := errors.As(err, &ge1); ok {
            fmt.Println("error group 1")
        } else if ok := errors.As(err, &ge2); ok {
            fmt.Println("error group 2")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("no error group")
        }
    }
}
```

Here I defined two error groups, so we can detect them with `errors.As` and you don't need to define any unused interface, but you need to create them by hand and there isn't any automatic grouping.